# How to build sequence diagram with 3 actors?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, system-design, system-analysis

Overview: This is my activity diagram for the stock management subsystem. I have 3 actors which are the admin, manager, and employee.

Question: Can someone explain to me how can I do my sequence diagram with 3 actors? In my sequence diagram, I need to have interface and controller (primary) not just the entity classes.

Note: I already made the sequence diagram for each of the actors but I don't know how to combine its kinda complicated lol.

[image: activity diagram]

Comment: Why would you put them in a SD at all? A SD is meant to show the collaboration of objects (class instances). Actors merely act as triggers. If you were to put all of the above into a single SD you clearly missed the point in creating diagrams the first place.

Comment: BTW Admin, Manager and Employee have to enter uid/pw all together in one action. Arte they going to launch an atomic missile? And `Maintain books` has a deadlock. 'Edit'/'Delete' a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being provocative, but this is a misunderstanding: **actors are by definition external** to the system.

In your activity diagram, you modelled activities of the sytem and grouped those activities in **partitions** (swimlanes. These partitions maybe somehow **related** to actors, but they are not themselves actors. It's just a (visual) grouping.

Likewise a sequence diagram is meant to represent an interaction **within** the system.  [In principle you should not show actors in a sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084215/system-sequence-diagram-can-system-request-input-from-actor/63098812#63098812).  Is is however a common practice and tolerated (although ambiguous) practice to do so:

- You could extend this notation and have a lifeline for each actor, but this would remain very ambiguous and would make a very complex interaction diagram. Even more if considering the combinatorial explosion os possible scenarios with so many actors.  You have nothing to gain to do so.
- If you really want actors in a SD, a better approach would be to separate concerns:  make one SD diagram per actor, that shows the interactions from the view point of the actor.  I understand that you already did this.  the activity diagram shows how this fits together.  (There is no need to have a giant SD diagrams showing all possible interactions)

Typically, the activity diagram with region is a convenient way to document a workflow with several actors. If you want to really focus on actors in a compelx workflow, a better alternative would proabably be to use [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation),  which is designed for business process modeling.