# If I had an object user in sequence diagram and I wanted to make that object interact with the interface,should I use it's own functions?

Tags: methods, uml, actor, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

My object user is a part of the sequence diagram for reporting accidents and it interacts with a user interface. User interface acts as a middle man between user and object from class report. To indicate the report,user must send his data to the user interface. So should I draw an arrow from user to interface that uses a function from user as I did in the photo or what should I do?

[image: sequence diagram]
If deemed useful, here the corresponding classes: [image: class diagram]

I searched for the solution online but found no useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence diagram seems to show the `User` as an actor. This is ambiguous, because actors are outside the system, whereas sequence diagram should show objects inside the system:

- while it is ambiguous, it is nevertheless a common practice as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098812/3723423) with additional recommendations.
- in your class diagram, there is a class `User` that seems to be different from the actor, and be inside the system. If your sequence diagram refers to an object of this class, prefer using a normal lifeline without the actor symbol, to avoid any confusion.
- your `User` lifeline sends messages that have the name of the operations of the `User` class. This is super-ambiguous, because the **messages send should correspond to operations of the receiver** and not the sender. So either your `User` class belongs to the system interface and you just need to avoid the naming ambiguity regarding the actor, or you need to rethink your messages.

**As explained in the comments**: if the user lifeline corresponds to a real user (e.g. a person), the messages could use informal wording instead of formal operations, as the user interacts with the system through input/output devices and doesn't call directly the operations. If you nevertheless use operations, use operation signatures of the receiver.

**Not related:**

You seem to use the `alt` with a message `continue()` that does not correspond to any operation of the receiver, just for the purpose of specifying what happens if the verification fails. If it's the case, you may prefer to use the more elegant [`break`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-break) instead: this allows you to specify exacltly the kind of unfortunate path you want to model, without an unnecessary `continue()` workaround.

Comment: Then if I wanted to resemble this should I set a user object that the actor interacts with from the outside?if that's the case what do I write on the arrows going from an actor to the interface?

Comment: To answer, I need to know: 1) in your current diagram, is the actor on the left the real actor (i.e. the person who uses your system) ? 2) What is the purpose of the User class in the class diagram: is it the user account? or is it a part of the UI?

Comment: For 1:yes it's the actual user . For 2:the user account

Comment: Ok. I'd recommend to rename your User class into UserAccount in the class diagram. In the sequence diagram, keep the actor as User. I'd suggest to show the exchange between actor and system's UI in plain text (enter username, enter password, ...) to show the informality of communication with user.  If you need, you could add a lifeline for an instance of UserAccount, and show with formal messages from the UI to the account what operation gets called after which interaction between actor and UI.

Comment: I think the OP's class design is broken. Hard to tell though with just that shard of information.

Comment: @qwerty_so there are plenty of unknowns. Is the report generated by the system or uploaded by the user? Why does the report verify the user and it's not done by a common service ? what's the architecture (mvc, ecb, ...)? How could user authentication go to more modern scheme (at least no password but a hash, but maybe dissociate user identity and authentication method which could be  token based ssl, 2fa, etc...). Here I cannot judge the design (design would btw be more for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). I try to help one step after the other, starting modestly with the UML question

Comment: I hope indeed that a better understanding of the interactions will help op to understand the problem and iteratively improve the model :-) If op would would share more details, it would be at risk of getting closed voted as "need more focus"

Answer (score 1):

Interaction in the physical world is usually *asynchroneous*. Since your `user` lifeline stands for the physical user, I would only use asynchroneous signals between it and the system.

The name of these signals should not include a verb like "send", since signals can be sent and received.

Your `system interface` component should have the corresponding receptions. Formally this would be required, but many tools allow a more flexible approach. I guess it is ok to not model the receptions, as long as you understand that they are to be defined on the target side of the signal message.

With the sequence diagram you define that the user sends the signals. If you want to show that in a class diagram, you could define an interface with receptions of the signals and a «use» dependency from the actor to the interface.